# Apache Spark: how to cancel job in code and kill running tasks?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a Spark application (version 1.6.0) on a Hadoop cluster with Yarn (version 2.6.0) in client mode. I have a piece of code that runs a long computation, and I want to kill it if it takes too long (and then run some other function instead).
Here is an example:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TIMEOUT_TEST")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val lst = List(1,2,3)
// setting up an infite action
val future = sc.parallelize(lst).map(while (true) _).collectAsync()

try {
    Await.result(future, Duration(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    println("success!")
} catch {
    case _:Throwable =>
        future.cancel()
        println("timeout")
}

// sleep for 1 hour to allow inspecting the application in yarn
Thread.sleep(60*60*1000)
sc.stop()
```

The timeout is set for 30 seconds, but of course the computation is infinite, and so Awaiting on the result of the future will throw an Exception, which will be caught and then the future will be canceled and the backup function will execute.
This all works perfectly well, except that the canceled job doesn't terminate completely: when looking at the web UI for the application, the job is marked as failed, but I can see there are still running tasks inside.

The same thing happens when I use SparkContext.cancelAllJobs or SparkContext.cancelJobGroup. The problem is that even though I manage to get on with my program, the running tasks of the canceled job are still hogging valuable resources (which will eventually slow me down to a near stop).

To sum things up: How do I kill a Spark job in a way that will also terminate all running tasks of that job? (as opposed to what happens now, which is stopping the job from running new tasks, but letting the currently running tasks finish)

UPDATE:
After a long time ignoring this problem, we found a messy but efficient little workaround. Instead of trying to kill the appropriate Spark Job/Stage from within the Spark application, we simply logged the stage ID of all active stages when the timeout occurred, and issued an HTTP GET request to the URL presented by the Spark Web UI used for killing said stages.

Comment: How about stopping the SparkContext in case of the exception, i.e. SparkContext.stop() And initialise a new SparkContext for subsequent jobs.

Comment: Unfortunately for me this is not an option, as the SparkContext is shared throughout the project. Stopping it and starting a new one will cause other modules to fail, since they are now holding a reference to a closed SparkContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of future visitors, Spark introduced the [Spark task reaper](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16189) since 2.0.3, which does address this scenario (more or less) and is a built-in solution.
Note that is can kill an Executor eventually, if the task is not responsive.

Moreover, [some built-in Spark sources of data](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/2aae220b536065f55b2cf644a2a223aab0d051d0) have been refactored to be more responsive to spark:

For the 1.6.0 version, Zohar's solution is a "messy but efficient" one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know it this answers your question.
My need was to kill jobs hanging for too much time (my jobs extract data from Oracle tables, but for some unknonw reason, seldom the connection hangs forever).

After some study, I came to this solution:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerJobStart}
import org.apache.spark.JobExecutionStatus

val MAX_JOB_SECONDS = 100
val statusTracker = sc.statusTracker;
val sparkListener = new SparkListener()  
{ 
    
    override def onJobStart(jobStart : SparkListenerJobStart)     
    {
        val jobId = jobStart.jobId
        val f = Future 
        {
            var c = MAX_JOB_SECONDS;
            var mustCancel = false;
            var running = true;
            while(!mustCancel && running)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                c = c - 1;
                mustCancel = c <= 0;
                val jobInfo = statusTracker.getJobInfo(jobId);
                if(jobInfo!=null)
                {
                    val v = jobInfo.get.status()
                    running = v == JobExecutionStatus.RUNNING
                }
                else
                    running = false;
            }
            if(mustCancel)
            {
              sc.cancelJob(jobId)
            }
        }
    }
}
sc.addSparkListener(sparkListener)
try
{
    val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM VERY_BIG_TABLE") //just an example of long-running-job
    println(df.count)
}
catch
{
    case exc: org.apache.spark.SparkException =>
    {
        if(exc.getMessage.contains("cancelled"))
            throw new Exception("Job forcibly cancelled")
        else
            throw exc
    }
    case ex : Throwable => 
    {
        println(s"Another exception: $ex")
    }
}
finally
{
    sc.removeSparkListener(sparkListener)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to setJobGroup:

"If interruptOnCancel is set to true for the job group, then job cancellation will result in Thread.interrupt() being called on the job's executor threads."

So the anno function in your map must be interruptible like this:

```
val future = sc.parallelize(lst).map(while (!Thread.interrupted) _).collectAsync()
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this won't work in my case, since I don't actually use collectAsync() in my code, but rather call a long running function from mllib using a future with timeout.