# Effectively kill/cancel Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a Spark job pulling data over JDBC, which sometimes hangs indefinitely without progress. It deserves investigation on its own why this happens, but anyway I'd like to cancel the job if it doesn't finish in predefined time.

This was asked before and I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691090/2890093) to set up timeout using SparkListener - this *almost* works, job itself is cancelled. However it still leaves running tasks behind, they're visible as still "running" in "Failed Jobs" section of Spark UI, like this:

[image]

I tried enabling [task reaper](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16189), which - if I understood well - is supposed to kill such tasks and print their thread dump for debugging, ie. added following config to the cluster:

```
spark.task.reaper.enabled = true
spark.task.reaper.killTimeout = 5
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything - no tasks are killed and no thread dump are printed to the log.

Any suggestion here? This is on Databricks, runtime 12.2 (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.3.2).